# How to make an external custom css (style.css) work with react component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a project going on, in several components, I need to put styles.
Bootstrap is working fine. But when I added `style.css` it does not seems to catch up.

I have checked the page source and the `style.css` file is linked properly to my `index.html` file.

**my file structure:**
[image]

This is the head tag of my `index.html`

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/style.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>News Scroller</title>
  </head>
```

Comment: I think u need to implement ** scss** to render your css properly in browser https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your dev environment (webpack)?

Comment: @Auriga No, I didn't.
can you please give me a source for how to do a refresh.

Comment: @ShojibMahabub refreshing environment means stop the server and start again.

Comment: yes i did that.

Comment: If you have your style.css in your `public` folder, it should work just fine like you have done it. Have you checked in the browser developer tools whether the style.css file actually gets loaded? What is the content of the style file? Do you have something suitable for debugging purposes in there that will always work, e.g. `body { background-color: red !important; }`?

Comment: @Aaaron 
I have tried by putting the file inside the public folder. I have checked, CSS file loads but the rules did not work.
I have changed the CSS rule from dev console, it works then. But the CSS rules from the file weren't there.
this is the project link: https://github.com/shojibMahabub/news-scroller/issues/1 can you please check this?

Comment: Your component has classes `input-group input-group-sm col-md-3` but your css selector is targeting `.input-group .input-group-sm .col-md-3` which means that it's looking for nested classes. Change the css selector to `.input-group.input-group-sm.col-md-3` by removing the spaces. These seem to be Bootstrap styles so you are most likely breaking Bootstrap functionality by adjusting the margins and float for your element.

Comment: It worked. Can you please repost your answer in the answer section so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what does your Webpack create when it compiles? How are you even putting your react component into your `index.html` now?

It seems like those are not there yet. These few things needs to be done:

1. There should be a div where your [react application is mounted](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html)
2. Your index.html shouldn't reference styles.css directly. It's usually [`imported` in your `App.js` or `Index.js](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/webpack-loaders-css-and-sass-2cc0079b5b3a), depending on your naming

Comment: I have tried your 2nd point. and I have a div with an id where my app should mount.
can you please check this out?
here is the issue link : https://github.com/shojibMahabub/news-scroller/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

In the style.css file, I was writing the CSS selector incorrectly.

I wrote this before : `.input-group .input-group-sm .col-md-3`
which is not able to select the className.
Instead of this I replaced the "" between the classNames and the CSS rules worked.